# Why doesn't Transmission respect my 1 KB/sec upload limit?

Tags: transmission, bandwidth

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, and have a question about the network activity of Transmission 2.22. Even though I set the global upload limit to 1kbs/s or even 0kb/s, my System Monitor/Conky shows  a steady 20-25 kb/s upload rate. I'm just curious, what's with this upload rate and is there any chance to reduce it?

Answer (score 2):

The upload speed limit of Transmission limits the data itself, not the BitTorrent protocol data. It will have a steady consumption above the limit, the amount of consumption relates to the number of torrents, peers, DHT being on and other. 
The only way to limit it altogether is to limit with outer resources, like creating a slowed down bridge connection or connecting through proxy on localhost.